# Calling three rest api's in curl

Tags: curl, shopify-api

I am using shopify rest api to get order data with curl init. I got data in forloop with two rest url's but after calling third I am getting "Exceeded 2 calls per second for api client. Reduce request rates resume uninterrupted service."

After calling third I am getting "Exceeded 2 calls per second for api client. Reduce request rates resume uninterrupted service."

Comment: You should throttle your request. Also you could consider using GraphQL API to make different kind of request in one single http request